# Image download and saving- android

Tags: android, gridview, android-activity, download, android-image

I have some images in gridview. when i click on the image , the image will open in another activity. In that activity i had a save button. When the save button is clicked the image should download and save in sd card. Now my question how to download and save the image.

this is my code

Main activity.java

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.beaches);

        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        /**
         * On Click event for Single Gridview Item
         * */
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                    int position, long id) {

                // Sending image id to FullScreenActivity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FullImageActivity.class);
                // passing array index
                i.putExtra("id", position);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        Button home=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        home.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));

            }
        });
    }
```

Fullimageactivity.java

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.beachfull);



        // get intent data
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // Selected image id
        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");
        ImageAdapter imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.full_image_view);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdapter.images[position]);

        Button dwnld = (Button)findViewById(R.id.download);
        dwnld.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });


    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is to save ImageFile from a URL

```
private String path;
private Bitmap bmImg;

void downloadFile(String fileUrl, String fileName) {
    // here you can add folder in which you want the image to be stored
      path = sdCard.getAbsolutePath() ;

    URL myFileUrl = null;
    try {
        myFileUrl = new URL(fileUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) myFileUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();

        if (bmImg != null) {
            bmImg.recycle();
        }

        bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path + "/" + fileName + ".jpg");
        bmImg.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, out);

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        // Toast.makeText(this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } 
}
```

Remember you also need permission for it in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```